# Transferring RAM from Dell T110 to Dell T1650

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell T110 II with 32GB of RAM (4 sticks) and a Dell T1605 with 16GB of RAM (4 sticks).
Would it be possible to take the RAM from the T110 and transfer it to the T1650? They appear to have the same type of RAM, and the T1650 will handle 32GB, but I'd like to confirm it would work before stripping the machines down.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say without knowing the exact model numbers of the Dell to read the spec. Go ahead and find out what the specs are on both machines' RAM, and compare them. If the machines are on and you don't want to turn them off yet, your OS should have the ability to tell you. If the machines are powered down, open 'em up and look.
You can also look up the Dell asset tag or exact model number of the servers on their site to see the specs and compare.